# Meaning of "one point of physics"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

We know that "of" has different usages. I'm wondering when a native English speaker reads the sentence

> **One point of physics** should be mentioned.

without any further context, what "one point of physics" means to him/her. Is its meaning unambiguous?

Comment: In any given real-world context it might be obvious that "point" means ***purpose / justification***, or ***fact / [small] detail*** (or indeed something else). But *without any further context* this question is MEANINGLESS!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I admit that my question may have been a bad one. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: [“Thank you.” “Of course, the **point of physics** is to understand why the treats come out when they do.” “Maybe for you. For dogs, the point is to get the treats.”](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+point+of+physics+is%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of context, **it is not clear** what "point of physics" means. If I jumped into the middle of a conversation and heard just this sentence, I would assume the speaker was offering a justification for studying physics (honestly, I'd probably judge his meaning by his appearance).

> One point of physics ?=? One reason why physics is valuable to know/study.

It is also possible that the speaker is using "point" as a loose synonym for "concept" or "result".

> One point of physics is that mass does not affect acceleration due to gravity.

In fact, the second explanation was my first instinct though upon further reflection, I believe the first is more likely.

Comment: Thanks. Can it also mean _a little bit of physics_? Or _some discussion related to physics_?

Comment: "little bit": No it can't. I do not think "point" can refer to a small amount. It more closely means "a small physical area". Something like, "a point of the mountain has coal buried beneath the surface." might be acceptable but it would definitely be more appropriate to say, "a point on the mountain..." I'm also not certain how "some discussion related to physics" can ever be implied by "point of physics."